# pandas: sorting/re-ordering columns for a multi-level column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
from pandas import Timestamp

values = [['IDX100', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '101'],
       ['IDX100', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '102'],
       ['IDX100', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '103'],
       ['IDX200', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '601'],
       ['IDX200', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '602'],
       ['IDX200', 'field1', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '603'],
       ['IDX100', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '201'],
       ['IDX100', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '202'],
       ['IDX100', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '203'],
       ['IDX200', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '701'],
       ['IDX200', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '702'],
       ['IDX200', 'field2', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '703'],
       ['IDX100', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '301'],
       ['IDX100', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '302'],
       ['IDX100', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '303'],
       ['IDX200', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-01 05:00:00'), '801'],
       ['IDX200', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-02 05:00:00'), '802'],
       ['IDX200', 'field3', Timestamp('1999-02-03 05:00:00'), '803']]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = ['identifier', 'code', 'date', 'value'])
```

After pivoting my dataframe i end up with the following:

```
df = df.pivot(index=['date'], columns=['identifier', 'code'], values=['value'])

                     value                                   
identifier          IDX100 IDX200 IDX100 IDX200 IDX100 IDX200
code                field1 field1 field2 field2 field3 field3
date                                                         
1999-02-01 05:00:00    101    601    201    701    301    801
1999-02-02 05:00:00    102    602    202    702    302    802
1999-02-03 05:00:00    103    603    203    703    303    803
```

I would however like to have the output look something like this:

```
identifier           IDX100                IDX200 
code                 field3 field2 field1  field3 field2 field1
date                                                         
1999-02-01 05:00:00    301    201    101   801    701    601
1999-02-02 05:00:00    302    202    102   802    702    602
1999-02-03 05:00:00    303    203    103   803    703    603
```

I can get close to this by doing something like this:

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

But this maintains the order of the level2 columns as field1, field2, field3. What i would like is to be able to sort that level differently..preferably based on a list that i provide.   For example i may want to sort it as field 3, field2, field1, or field2, field1, field3.

can anyone help with this?

Comment: Could you please provide the code that can reproduce your input dataframe, df? Especially if dataframe includes a multi-index, need the code that can create the dataframe in order to reproduce your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example Code**

Especially if dataframe includes a multi-index, need the code that can create the dataframe in order to reproduce your dataframe.

this time, i provide code for you.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[101, 601, 201, 701, 301, 801], [102, 602, 202, 702, 302, 802], [103, 603, 203, 703, 303, 803]]

idx = pd.Index(['1999-02-01 05:00:00', '1999-02-02 05:00:00', '1999-02-03 05:00:00'], name='date')
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], ['IDX100', 'IDX200']], names=['code', 'identifier']).swaplevel(0, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
```

df

[image]

---

**Code**

lets sort field2 -> field1 -> field3

use `sort_index`

```
order = ['field2', 'field1', 'field3']
m = {key: num for num, key in enumerate(order)}
out = df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map(m) if x.name == 'code' else x)
```

out:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A canonical and robust way would be to use an ordered [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html):

```
codes = pd.CategoricalDtype(['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], ordered=True)

out = (df.astype({'code': codes})
         .pivot(index=['date'], columns=['identifier', 'code'], values='value')
         .sort_index(axis=1)
       )
```

Or, to sort after pivoting:

```
codes = pd.CategoricalDtype(['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], ordered=True)

out = df.pivot(index=['date'], columns=['identifier', 'code'], values='value')

out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(out.columns.to_frame().astype({'code': codes}))

out = out.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
identifier          IDX100               IDX200              
code                field2 field1 field3 field2 field1 field3
date                                                         
1999-02-01 05:00:00    201    101    301    701    601    801
1999-02-02 05:00:00    202    102    302    702    602    802
1999-02-03 05:00:00    203    103    303    703    603    803
```

Comment: thanks much.  which i could mark both answers